# XPath to query multiple selectors

Tags: php, regex, xpath

I want to get values and attributes from a selector 
and then get attributes and values of its children based on a query.

allow me to give an example.

this is the structure

```
<div class='message'>
   <div>
   <a href='http://www.whatever.com'>Text</a>
   </div>

   <div>
    <img src='image_link.jpg' />
   </div>

</div>

<div class='message'>
   <div>
   <a href='http://www.whatever2.com'>Text2</a>
   </div>

   <div>
    <img src='image_link2.jpg' />
   </div>

</div>
```

So I would like to make a query to match all of those once.

Something like this:

```
 //$dom is the DomDocument() set up after loaded HTML with $dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $dom_xpath->query('//div[@class="message"], //div[@class="message"] //a, //div[@class="message"] //img');

foreach($elements as $ele){
   echo $ele[0]->getAttribute('class'); //it should return 'message'
   echo $ele[1]->getAttribute('href'); //it should return 'http://www.whatever.com' in the 1st loop, and 'http://www.whatever2.com' in the second loop
   echo $ele[2]->getAttribute('src'); //it should return image_link.jpg in the 1st loop and 'image_link2.jpg' in the second loop
}
```

Is there some way of doing that using multiple xpath selectors like I did in the example? to avoid making queries all the time and save some CPU.

Comment: the query method returns a DOMNodeList. Iterating that DOMNodeList will give the DOMNode subtype. None of them can be accessed with ArrayAccess, so the code you show is impossible with regular DOM features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//div[@class='message'])[$k]//@*
```

This selects all three attributes that belong to the $k-th `div` (and any of its descendants) in the document whose `class` attribute has string value `"message"`

You can evaluate `N` such XPath expressions -- for `$k` from 1 to `N`, where `N` is the total count of `//div[@class='message']`

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//div[@class='message']">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "(//div[@class='message'])[0+$vPos]//@*"/>
 ================
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat('name = ', name(), ' value = ', ., '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped in a single top element to become well-formed):

```
<html>
    <div class='message'>
        <div>
            <a href='http://www.whatever.com'>Text</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='image_link.jpg' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='message'>
        <div>
            <a href='http://www.whatever2.com'>Text2</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='image_link2.jpg' />
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

**The XPath expression is evaluated twice and the selected attributes are formatted and output**:

```
name = class value = message
name = href value = http://www.whatever.com
name = src value = image_link.jpg

 ================
name = class value = message
name = href value = http://www.whatever2.com
name = src value = image_link2.jpg

 ================
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the union operator (`|`) in a single expression like this:

```
//div[@class="message"]|//div[@class="message"]//a|//div[@class="message"]//img
```

Note that this will return a flattened result set (so to speak). In other words, you won't access the elements in groups of three like your example shows. Instead, you'll just iterate everything the expressions matched (in document order). For this reason, it might be even smarter to simply iterate the nodes returned by `//div[@class="message"]` and use DOM methods to access their children (for the other elements).